# MySQL UPDATE -- ignore records not in CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

How do you ignore records not inside the case statement when using CASE/WHEN/THEN?

For example, this statement will update three matching records as expected but will make all student records that do not match a WHEN/THEN clause to NULL

```
UPDATE table SET student = (CASE WHEN student = '10' THEN '100412'
                                 WHEN student = '17' THEN '100295' 
                                 WHEN student = '26' THEN '100981'
                            END)
WHERE year = '2019';
```

How can you skip over records not inside the CASE statement and only change records that have a matching clause?

Comment: try WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a default case for that:

```
UPDATE table SET student = (CASE WHEN student = '10' THEN '100412'
                                 WHEN student = '17' THEN '100295' 
                                 WHEN student = '26' THEN '100981'
                                 ELSE student
                            END)
WHERE year = '2019';
```

Otherwise, if you want to minimize the load, just add all known `student` values to the `WHERE` clause. This triggers an update only on those rows that are really affected by a change

Comment: but this SQL would update all records, even if the updated value is same as old value ‍♂️

Comment: @sudoz can you explain that further? Does this query yield wrong data?

Answer (score 5):

For skipping records not in case statement, you can use something like this

```
UPDATE table SET student = (CASE WHEN student = '10' THEN '100412'
                                 WHEN student = '17' THEN '100295' 
                                 WHEN student = '26' THEN '100981'
                            END)
WHERE year = '2019' AND student IN ('10','17','26');
```

Answer (score 3):

There a two solutions I think :

1. Add a where clause

```
UPDATE table SET student = (CASE WHEN student = '10' THEN '100412'
                                 WHEN student = '17' THEN '100295' 
                                 WHEN student = '26' THEN '100981'
                            END)
WHERE year = '2019' AND student IN ('10','17','26');
```

2. Use else statement but that will scan the whole table for nothing :

```
UPDATE table SET student = (CASE WHEN student = '10' THEN '100412'
                                 WHEN student = '17' THEN '100295' 
                                 WHEN student = '26' THEN '100981'
                                 ELSE student
                            END)
WHERE year = '2019';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` or  `=` operator

```
WHERE year = '2019' AND (student = '10' or student = '17' or student  ='26');
```

Comment: Not good.  WIthout parentheses, you get  `WHERE (year = '2019' AND student = '10') or student = '17' or student  ='26'`, which is _not_ what you need.

Comment: it could be like this `WHERE year = '2019' AND (student = '10' or student = '17' or student  ='26');`