# Update multiple rows with a single query in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I am trying to update multiple rows with a single query using Postgres. Here is what I am trying to do: If the `sku` is `0001`, then i want to update `field_1` to `foo`. Repeat with all the other skus.

When I run this code, this code correctly updates the correct row and field. BUT it turns all the other records' `field_1` into `null`. What code should be added here to prevent that?

```
UPDATE table
    SET field_1 = ( case WHEN sku = '0001' then 'foo'
                         WHEN sku = '0002' then 'bar'
                         WHEN sku = '0003' then 'baz'
                    END
                   )
```

BEFORE running the query

| sku | field_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | dummy_1 |
| 0002 | dummy_2 |
| 0003 | dummy_3 |
| 0004 | dummy_4 |
| 0005 | dummy_5 |
| 0006 | dummy_6 |

AFTER running the query

| sku | field_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | foo |
| 0002 | bar |
| 0003 | baz |
| 0004 | null |
| 0005 | null |
| 0006 | null |

Comment: so define an ELSE in your CASE clause

Comment: Please correct the tags, because mysql and postgresql are different DBMS systems. You should only use the one that your are actually using.

Comment: That's just a duplicate. You should google for a solution before asking a question here. See [MySQL UPDATE -- ignore records not in CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58860583/mysql-update-ignore-records-not-in-case-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `WHERE` clause which restricts the SKUs targeted for update:

```sql
UPDATE table
SET field_1 = CASE sku WHEN '0001' THEN 'foo'
                       WHEN '0002' THEN 'bar'
                       WHEN '0003' THEN 'baz' END
WHERE sku IN ('0001', '0002', '0003');
```